# Ansible “become” plugin doesn't work when password variable is set in playbook

Tags: ansible, sudo, su

I have a remote user without sudo and servers with forbidden ssh for root.
So I try to use next approach for privilege escalation:

```
- block:
  - name: Get hardware password
    shell: |
      slcli --format json hardware detail --passwords {{ hostname }}
    register: json_answer
    delegate_to: localhost
  - name: set hardwareInfo variable
    set_fact: 
      hardwareInfo: "{{ json_answer.stdout|from_json }}"
  - name: set password variable
    set_fact: 
      ansible_become_pass: "{{ hardwareInfo | to_json | from_json | json_query(password_query) }}"
    vars: 
      password_query: "users[?username==`root`].password"
  no_log: true

- name: Install repository deb
  shell: |
    dpkg -i {{ deb_repo_url }}
  become: yes
  become_method: su
  become_user: root
```

But I get error:

> { "msg": "Incorrect su password", "_ansible_no_log": false }

I checked out *ansible_become_pass* variable and it has correct password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that my variable was in wrong format (array instead of string).

```
{
    "changed": false,
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_become_pass": [
            "my_password"
        ]
    },
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

Changed set_fact to this and now it's works

```
- name: set password variable
  set_fact: 
    ansible_become_pass: "{{ hardwareInfo | to_json | from_json | json_query(password_query) | join('') }}"
```